# Prove that $ \sum \frac{2^k}{k}$ is divisible by $2^M$

Tags: calculus, arithmetic

For each integer $M > 0$, there ${\bf exists}$ an $n$ such that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{ 2^k}{k} $$

is divisible by $2^M$

${\bf try}$ Im struggling a bit to visualize this exercise. So, I tried to see for concrete number, for instance take $M=1$, then $n=2$ works: as

$$ 2 + \dfrac{2^1}{2} = 2^1 (1 + 2 )$$

Now, take $M=2$ and factor

$$ 2^{2} \underbrace{ \left( \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{2}{3} + \dfrac{2^4}{4} ... + \dfrac{2^{n-2} }{n} \right) }_{(*)}$$

now, we need to choose $n$ so that $(*)$ is an integer. Im unable to do so. Any help?

Comment: I don't understand.  The usual proof that Harmonic numbers can't be integers invokes Bertrand's postulate to find a prime $p$ such that $\frac 1p$ appears in the sum but $\frac 1{2p}$ does not.  That prime must be in the denominator, and outside of a couple small $n$ we can't have $p=2$.

Comment: When $n=1$ the sum has only one term, so I don't understand the first calculation.

Comment: Clarification: "divisible by $2^M$" means that the sum can be written as $2^M p/q$ with $2 \not\mid q$. That is, the 2-adic valuation of the partial sums converge to $0$.

Comment: Trevor: WTF? Pisco: You don’t make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A087910](https://oeis.org/A087910) is the $2$-adic valuation of the finite sum. The sequence entry claims "[...] asked for a proof that a(n) tends to infinity with n. While this is immediate from the theory of the 2-adic logarithm, elementary proofs are available. [...]"

Comment: Notice that the question currently asks for a proof of "[...] there **exists** an $n$ [...]" and **not** the stronger "[...] for **all** $n$ large enough [...]".

Comment: Duplicate: [Proving $2+2^2/2+2^3/3+2^4/4+\cdots=0$ elementarily](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816184/proving-222-223-324-4-cdots-0-elementarily) (Although this question seems to have gotten a better response by Trevor.)

Comment: @lulu Who are you talking to? Did someone bring up harmonic numbers? (Also $p=2$ can be used to show $H_n$ is not an integer without Bertrand's postulate by showing only one denominator in $H_n$ is divisible by the largest power of $2$ that is $\le n$; I'd call that the "usual proof" personally.)

Comment: @runway44  Not sure I see your point.  Are you disputing my claim that Bertrand is the ":standard" way  to show what I claimed?  Ok..  It's "one of the standard ways".  My point, of course, was that the Bertrand argument also showed that the OP's numbers can not be integers (after a few small cases).  Subsequent commenters have sensibly proposed that, despite what was written,  the OP really intended to ask about $2-$adic valuations.  That is certainly possible and if that is the case then of course integrality is off the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right so the "elementary answer." There are actually a couple that I've seen. One is cited by Gouvêa in his *p-adic numbers* book (Gouvêa, like me, also said the problem was too difficult to work out the answer from scratch).

The solution Gouvêa cites is Exercise 10.10 of D. P. Parent *Exercises in Number Theory* (1984).

The rough idea there (assuming I'm summarizing correctly) is

$$ 0 = \frac{1 - (1 - 2)^{2^n}}{2^n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{2^n} (-1)^{k+1}2^k \frac{1}{2^n}\binom{2^n}{k} \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac{2^k}{k} \pmod{2^h} $$

for $n \ge h$. Plus there's some other work to compare this with the partial sums that are not powers of $2$.

---

The next two solutions I found cited by the OEIS (https://oeis.org/A087910). Namely the two solutions given for the 2002 Sydney University Mathematical Society Problems Competitions [Problem 9](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/SUMSCOMP/).

**Solution 1 Summary**

If $n$ is even then

$$ 1 = (-1)^n = (1 - 2^n) = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-2)^k. \tag{1} $$

Subtract 1 and divide by $n$ to get

$$ 0 = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac1n \binom{n}{k}(-2)^k. $$

Then

$$ \frac1n \binom{n}{k} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!} = \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} + n\frac{m_{n,k}}{k!} \tag{2}$$

for some integer $m_{n,k}$ (separate the term $(-1)(-2)\cdots(-k+1)$ from all the terms divisible by $n$).

By $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^k}{k} = n \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{(-2)^km_{n,k}}{k!}$$

Then you use a well known fact that $v_2(k)! \le O(k)$. Thus

$$ v_2\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^k}{k} \right) = v_2(n) + v_2\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{(-2)^km_{n,k}}{k!} \right) \ge v_2(n). $$

Now we can see that when $n = 2^k$ this tends to infinity.

---

**Solution 2 Summary**

First show that

$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^k}{k} = \frac{2^n}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{k}}. $$

Next, use the well-known formula $$v_2(n!) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac n{2^i} \right\rfloor$$ to get

$$ v_2\left( \binom{n}{k} \right) = v_2(n!) - v_2(k!) - v_2((n - k)!) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac n{2^i} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac k{2^i} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac {n-k}{2^i} \right\rfloor. $$

Then by some analysis,

$$v_2\left( \binom{n-1}{k} \right) \le r \text{ if } 2^r + 1 \le n \le 2^{r + 1}. $$

So if $n$ is even and $2^r + 1 \le n \le 2^{r + 1}$ then

$$ v_2\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^k}{k} \right) \ge n - r. $$

And the result follows.

---

You'll have to see the solutions I linked to if you want all the details, they wouldn't fit in one answer. I hope this gives you some appreciation for the $2$-adic logarithm approach.

Answer (score 4):

First, an important definition

> **Definition** the $2$-adic valuation $v_2$ is given by
> $$v_2\left( 2^n\frac{p}{q} \right) = n$$
> where $p, q$ are odd (not divisible by $2$).

For instance $v_2(12/5) = 2$ since we can write $12/5$ as $2^2 \frac{3}{5}$.

In this language, what we want to show is that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} v_2\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^k}{k} \right) = \infty. \tag{$*$}$$

---

In my opinion the best/most conceptual/requires the least tricks way to prove this is to identify the infinite series

$$ \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k} $$

as the $2$-adic logarithm of $-1$. That is, it is $-\log(1 - 2) = -\log(-1)$. Recall that the logarithm is given by the series

$$-\log(1 - x) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}. $$

Given this, and assuming that basic properties of logarithms still hold in the $2$-adics, we have

$$\log(-1) + \log(-1) = 2 \log(-1) = \log((-1)^2) = \log(1) = 0. $$

Therefore $\log(-1) = 0$ as a $2$-adic number.

Well the series converges to $0$ in the $2$-adics if and only if the partial sums grow to $\infty$ in $2$-adic valuation. I.e. The series converges to $0$ if and only if $(*)$ holds.

This requires some work to understand:

1. what does it mean to converge in the $2$-adic valuation
2. do these series converge?
3. is $\log(xy) = \log x + \log y$ still true and when?

For all these questions, I must refer to [Keith Conrad's notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf). The identity $(*)$ is discussed at the top of page 29 (Example 8.10) and I'm not going to fit 29 pages of exposition in here.

However, I will say that this approach is much nicer than the non-logarithm approach. Because that approach requires several very hard-to-find tricks. If I were locked in a room with no internet or any other references and I had to prove this fact, I would pick the p-adic logarithm approach because at least then I have some idea what needs to be done.

---

I'll try to find a "more elementary" approach in a separate answer (this one's getting sort of long). But I'll warn you now: don't expect it to be easy to understand or enlightening.

Answer (score -1):

This certainly doesn't seem true

If any $n > 2$ there is a prime $p$ so that $2<p \le n < 2p$ (Bertands postulate) and so

And so if $2^m| \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {2^k}k$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {2^k}k=W$ is as an integer.  And so $W-\frac {2^p}p$ is not an integer.

But $W - \frac {2^p}p= \frac {pW - 2^p}p$ is a fraction in lowest terms.

Which means $\sum_{k=1;k\ne p}^n \frac {2^k}k = \frac {pW -2^p}p$.  But be figuring out the least common denominator of $\frac {2^k}{k}; k\ne p$ we get the lets common denominater is $\operatorname{lcm}(k; k\ne p)$.  But that will not reduce so $\frac{pW-2^p}p$ unless $p$ divides into $\operatorname{lcm}(k; k\ne p)$.

Which it clearly can't as $\operatorname{lcm}(k; k\ne p)$ does not have $p$ as a prime divisor of any of the $k$ terms.

SO.... unless I'm making a bonehead error, this is not possible.

Not only is this not true  $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {2^k}k$ is never an integer if $n > 2$.

..... unless I'm making a boneheaded error.

Comment: The claim is not that it is an *integer* divisible by $2^M$, the claim is that it is a *rational number* divisible by $2^M$. The first few terms are $$2^1, 2^2, 2^2 \frac53, 2^5 \frac13, 2^8 \frac{1}{15}. $$

Comment: Admittedly "divisible by $2^M$" might not be the best language.

Comment: But $2^M$ is an integer so there are not any *non*integers divisible by $2^M$.  To say $p$ divides $q$ is to say there is an integer $K$ (and, yes, $K$ *must* be an integer) so that $pK = q$.  It's true that $q$ does not need to be an integer (after all $\frac 34$ divides evenly into $2\frac 14 = 3\cdot \frac 34$) but if $q$ is *not* an integer neither is $p$.  To have $2^M K = \sum\frac {2^k}{k}$ as $2^M$ and $K$ are both integers we must have $\sum \frac {2^k}k$ also be an integer.

Comment: "Admittedly "divisible by 2M" might not be the best language."  "divisible by $2^M$ means something *very* precise and clear.  To say $W$ is divisible by $2^m$ means that $\frac W{2^m}$ is an integer.  Nothing more; nothing less.  And if $\frac W{2^m}$ is an integer, and $2^m$ is an integer then $W$ must *also* be an integer.

Comment: If you mean something *ELSE* than $\frac {\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {2^k}k}{2^M} \in \mathbb Z$ then you **you** better *explain* what you do actually mean.  If you mean $\frac {\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {2^k}k}{2^m} \in \mathbb R$ then the result is trivial.  And I can't really think of any other things it can mean.

Comment: Hey I didn't write the problem, don't yell at me. It means that the sum is in $2^M \mathbb Z_{(2)}$. Where $\mathbb Z_{(2)} = \{ p/q : q\text{ is odd}\}$.

Comment: I get where your misunderstanding is coming from, fleablood, since the definition of divisibility you cite is used almost exclusively in the context of integers. You say you can't think of any other things it could mean - maybe that's true... Some background in p-adic number theory would have helped (which OP failed to signal to their audience, so they have fault), since that is the context in which "divisibility" takes the form it does here. If you'd read Trevor's first comment under OP (which appeared two hours before you posted your answer) this misunderstanding could have been avoided!

Comment: So, to be clear, here divisible by $2^m$ essentially means that $W/2^m$ is a **p-adic** integer. For rational $W$, that is equivalent to what Trevor said so much earlier: $W$ is divisible by $2^m$ if it is $2^mp/q$ where $2\nmid q$. It is unclear if OP realizes the gravity of their mistake in leaving this clarification out of the question they presumably pulled from another source.